# PHP walker class arrays and objects

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I am working with the walker class to create a menu for a WordPress theme and the code I have is;

```
class Walker_Nav_Primary extends Walker_Nav_menu {

    function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ){ //ul
        $indent = str_repeat("\t",$depth);
        $submenu = ($depth > 0) ? ' sub-menu' : '';
        $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"dropdown-menu$submenu depth_$depth\">\n";
    }

    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ){ //li a span

        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat("\t",$depth) : '';

        $li_attributes = '';
        $class_names = $value = '';

        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;

        $classes[] = ($args->walker->has_children) ? 'dropdown' : '';
        $classes[] = ($item->current || $item->current_item_ancestor) ? 'active' : '';
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;
        if( $depth && $args->walker->has_children ){
            $classes[] = 'dropdown-submenu';
        }

        $class_names =  join(' ', apply_filters('nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
        $class_names = ' class="' . esc_attr($class_names) . '"';

        $id = apply_filters('nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'.$item->ID, $item, $args);
        $id = strlen( $id ) ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

        $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names . $li_attributes . '>';

        $attributes = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="' . esc_attr($item->attr_title) . '"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target ) ? ' target="' . esc_attr($item->target) . '"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn ) ? ' rel="' . esc_attr($item->xfn) . '"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url ) ? ' href="' . esc_attr($item->url) . '"' : '';

        $attributes .= ( $args->walker->has_children ) ? ' class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"' : '';

        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a' . $attributes . '>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= ( $depth == 0 && $args->walker->has_children ) ? ' <b class="caret"></b></a>' : '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        $output .= apply_filters ( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );

    }

}
```

However, when a friend viewed the theme he was seeing the message below, I and no one else saw this message, and the menu works fine.

> Strict standards: Declaration of Walker_Nav_Primary::start_lvl()
>   should be compatible with Walker_Nav_Menu::start_lvl(&$output,$depth =
>   0, $args = Array) in .../inc/walker.php on line 0

So he made a couple of changes the first was to address this error by putting in $args =array() in the start_lvl function which as missing, but then he writes that $args is not an object its a array so you can't do $args->something, you have to do $args['something'], which gives the code;

```
class Walker_Nav_Primary extends Walker_Nav_menu {

    function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) { //ul
        $indent = str_repeat("\t",$depth);
        $submenu = ($depth > 0) ? ' sub-menu' : '';
        $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"dropdown-menu$submenu depth_$depth\">\n";
    }

    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ){ //li a span
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat("\t",$depth) : '';
        $li_attributes = '';
        $class_names = $value = '';
        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;

        $classes[] = ($args['walker']->has_children) ? 'dropdown' : '';

        $classes[] = ($item->current || $item->current_item_ancestor) ? 'active' : '';
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;
        if( $depth && $args['walker']->has_children ){
            $classes[] = 'dropdown-submenu';
        }
        $class_names =  join(' ', apply_filters('nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
        $class_names = ' class="' . esc_attr($class_names) . '"';
        $id = apply_filters('nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'.$item->ID, $item, $args);
        $id = strlen( $id ) ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';
        $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names . $li_attributes . '>';
        $attributes = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="' . esc_attr($item->attr_title) . '"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target ) ? ' target="' . esc_attr($item->target) . '"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn ) ? ' rel="' . esc_attr($item->xfn) . '"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url ) ? ' href="' . esc_attr($item->url) . '"' : '';
        $attributes .= ( $args['walker']->has_children ) ? ' class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"' : '';
        $item_output = $args['before'];
        $item_output .= '<a' . $attributes . '>';
        $item_output .= $args['link_before'] . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args['link_after'];
        $item_output .= ( $depth == 0 && $args['walker']->has_children ) ? ' <b class="caret"></b></a>' : '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args['after'];
        $output .= apply_filters ( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }
}
```

However, when I run the code I get the following error

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in

referring to lines where

```
$classes[] = ($args->walker->has_children) ? 'dropdown' : '';
```

has been changed to

```
$classes[] = ($args['walker']->has_children) ? 'dropdown' : '';
```

We are both on the same PHP and WordPress so I don't understand why it is working for him and not me, and which is the correct method.

Can anyone shed any light?

Comment: OK firstly you have to be sure is $args array or object ? or it is inconsistent and then you have to be sure is there any key or property named as `walker` then you should check if the key or property is an object or not. I will make an answer to give you best usage but you have to be sure is $args  array or object.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure `$args` is an array place this code before the use of `$args`

```
if (!isset($args['walker']) || !(is_object($args['walker']) && isset($args['walker']->has_children)) {
   $classes[] = '';
   $args = (object) array('walker' => array('has_children' => false));
}
```

But if the `$args` an object then use following :

```
if (!isset($args->walker) || !(is_object($args->walker) && isset($args->walker->has_children)) {
   $classes[] = '';
   $args = (object) array('walker' => array('has_children' => false));
}
```

If it is inconsistent firstly make this consistent, be sure $args array or object.